# Terminal Command: start or stop process if it's running or not

Tags: macos, glassfish, terminal

I have a glassfish install and I would like to have a simple terminal command checking if it's running. If it is, it will shutdown the process. Or if it not running, it will start the server.

To start the server I can enter:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-3.1.1/bin/./asadmin start-domain domain
```

To stop the server I can enter:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-3.1.1/bin/.asadmin stop-domain domain
```

I will would like to make a simple Alfred.app script than can start this domain if it's not running, or stop it if it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to note in a file the process ID of the server when it starts, and have another script check to see if that process is running.

For example, script A (to run the server unconditionally):

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-3.1.1/bin/./asadmin start-domain domain
# file name is arbitrary
pgrep whateverTheProcessNameIs > ~/.glassfish-server.pid
```

And in script B:

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=`pgrep -F ~/.glassfish-server.pid` # file chosen in script A
if [ "x$pid" = "x" ] ; then
  # process has died; restart by running script A
  /path/to/scriptA
fi
```

**Note that only Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) installs `pgrep` by default; otherwise you'd have to use some other method (like parsing `ps` output) to see what processes are running.**

As far as how to run this check periodically, there are various ways.  I'm assuming Alfred will run any script that is executable (`chmod +x scriptA scriptB`) but I don't know for sure.